# Finding all children for a parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I have a particular relationship that is like follows

> Class School has_many Departments, Department belongs_to School
>
> Class Department has_many Teachers, Teacher belongs_to department

and I want to be able to list all of the Teachers belonging to a school, based on when they were hired (in this case just "created_at") but not organized by department.  I'm hoping ruby on rails has a really cool find function for this :D but if not how would I go about retrieving this list?  Perhaps something similar below would work to build an array - and if so how would you organize it by the Teach created_at value?

```
School.departments.each.teachers.each do |t|
   teacher_list << t
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `has_many :through` for teachers so that you can query teachers directly on the `School`:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :departments
  has_many :teachers, :through => :departments

  ...

end
```

You can then query teachers like so:

```
@school = School.find(id)
@school.teachers.order(:created_at)
```

That should be enough to give you the idea.

Comment: perfect!  I'll mess around with it and get back with a response!